# How to get count of elements in columnA which are not present in ColumnB

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, counting

I have two columns:

```
A         B
Hello    Good
How      Hello
Are      Morning
You      You
```

I want the count of elements in A which are not present in B (`How , Are` here), The answer would be 2 in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> which are not present in B

```
=COUNTA(IFERROR(FILTER(A1:A, NOT(COUNTIF(B1:B, A1:A)))))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 1):

```
=COUNTIF(FILTER(A:A, ISNA(MATCH(A:A, B:B, 0))),"<>")
```

[image]

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24884807)

Comment: @babon A detail: The answer that doesn't really answer the question, is right down here, made by @user11982798, it really doesn't answer the question. Because the boy's data is in ```A``` and ```B```, he gave an answer with data in ```I``` and ```H```. It has nothing to do.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24888241)

Comment: @BrondbyIF my bad. Flag me for inconvenience.

Comment: @AlekseyPotapov Something is going on, more than five people voted to ban this answer from me, I think there is some flaw in StackOverflow's analysis system

Comment: Aha, I checked the edit history. 1-line code Answers are being deleted due to lack of description. You added the description (at least the screenshot from Excel - this gives more context) so now I upvoted it to indicate answer usefulness.

Comment: @AlekseyPotapov ah, i understand now! Thanks for explanation!

Comment: Just to sum up, I would recommend you to check SO's official [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) article along with the famous [blog post](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully/) from [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet). Actually, I have read that blog post yesterday and find it quite interesting :)

Answer (score -1):

Try with sum:

```
=sum(arrayformula( 
  if( isna( vlookup(filter(A1:A ,A1:A<>""), 
      (filter({B1:B,row(B1:B)} ,B1:B<>"")),2,false )),1,0)))
```

with count:

```
=count(arrayformula( 
  if( isna( vlookup(filter(A1:A ,A1:A<>""), 
      (filter({B1:B,row(B1:B)} ,B1:B<>"")),2,false )),1,"")))
```

Comment: Can you explain why is it that this would be a good solution?

Comment: I don't think what I answer is a good solution, but I'm happy if it can help me to solve it and contribute in this forum.